# Let $n \geqslant 3$. Show that the equation $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$ has exactly $4$ solutions modulo $2^n$

Tags: congruences

Okay, so I've been trying for hours to try prove this

Let $n \geqslant 3$. Show that the equation $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$ has exactly $4$ solutions  modulo $2^n$.

I tried using induction but I just can't work it out, I think I'm just missing something simple. however, I know how to find the $4$ solutions, such as when  $n=3$, the $4$ solutions $1,3,5,7$,  and when $n=4$ the $4$ solutions are $1,7,9,15$, and when $n=5$ the $4$ solutions are $1,15,17,31$   etc. …  so how do i prove for all $n \geqslant 3$ that there are exactly $4$ solutions $\mod 2^n$? Using induction?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/quadratic_congruences.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}$ has exactly four solution incongruent solutions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25128/prove-that-x2-equiv-1-pmod2k-has-exactly-four-solution-incongruent-sol)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A solution modulo $2^{k+1}$ is also a solution modulo $2^k$. So if you know that modulo $2^k$ the only possibilities are $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and $a_4$, then modulo 
$2^{k+1}$ the only possibilities are $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and $a_1+2^k,a_2+2^k,a_3+2^k,a_4+2^k$. Just check which of those work.

In other words, yes, you have found the correct scheme, and can prove it by induction.